# Java How to get a value from different class

Tags: java, class

I got this code sample

```
public class Plane {
private String id;
private Flight flight;
private int seats; 

public int getSeats() {
    return seats;
}

}

public class Flight {
private String id;
private Set<Passenger> passengers;
private Set<Employee> crew;  
private String destination;
private int flighTime; // minutes past Midnight
private int flightDuration; // in minutes
}
```

And now I'm trying to implement Flight's method, Add1Passenger, so I need to look up to Plane, if there is a free seat ( number of seats is less than number of Flight's passengers) but I don't know how to do such thing. Or is there any better solution ?

Comment: Have you considered googling your title verbatim? A cursory search reveals innumerable duplicates on this site alone in addition to many other resources regarding this problem. It sounds like you're missing some fundamentals of object oriented programming. This isn't something you can expect us to teach you. You need to pick up a tutorial or some other introductory material. Before asking again please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can use the POJO classes and initialize the values using setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a getter method to your Plane class that is public.

```
public class Plane {  
    private String id; 
    private Flight flight; 
    private int seats;

    public int getSeats(){
        return seats;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can have the Plane be a property of the Flight and pass in in via the constructor.  So now you have a Plane associated with the flight

```
public class Flight {
    private String id;
    private Set<Passenger> passengers;
    private Set<Employee> crew;  
    private String destination;
    private int flighTime; // minutes past Midnight
    private int flightDuration; // in minutes
    private Plane aircraft; // the aircraft assigned to the flight

    public Flight(Plane airplane){
        aircraft = airplane;
    }

    public Boolean addPassenger(Passenger passenger){
        if(aircraft.getSeats() > passengers.size()){
           passenges.add(passenger);
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In theory you could go the other route of passing in the plane as an argument to addPassenger but one could make the argument that different instances of a plane could be passed in to the flight and vice versa if you pass in flight to the plane object, you can have different flights on a plane, which could be fine if that is a legit business requirement, but if the flight have different destinations that would not make sense.

Comment: Yeah, but this getter is unreachable from Flight class because this class don't know anything about Plane class, so maybe method Add1Passenger should be a Plane method ?

Comment: @J1rka You have GOT to pick up a basic tutorial. It's not unreachable, you just don't know how to do some basic object oriented programming.

Comment: Why would the flight class not know about the plane class? You have passengers, crew a destination, etc. What are the passengers going to fly on? How can you have a flight with all the details of a flight excluding the plane that you are going to fly on?

Comment: I just don't know how can I get to the Plane class FROM the Flight.. 
I got some Plane with associated with some flight. Now how can I get for example Plane id, from the flight associated with the plane ?

Comment: You have multiple options here.  But looking at your existing flight class I think you should add a plane property to the flight, "private Plane aircraft;" for example.  There is a lot of stuff missing from your Flight class like the constructor so I'm not sure how u set the other properties of your class, like the cres and passengers.  But I would think you can pass the plane in via the Flight constructor " public Flight(Plane airplane) { aircraft = airplane;}"  or you can pass the Plane as an argument to the addPassengerToFlight method, but to me that doesn't seem right .. lemme update answ

Answer (score 0):

here you are u can also make 3rd class where you store both classes, you have to ALWAYS Inicialize new object in constructor dont forget

```
public class Plane {
private String id;
private Flight flight;
private int seats; 

Plane(Flight flight) {
   this.flight = flight;
}
public void addPasagerToFlight() {
    if (this.seats > flight.getPassagers()) {
        flight.addPasagerToFlight();
    }
    }
  }

public class Flight {
private String id;
private Set<Passenger> passengers;
private Set<Employee> crew;  
private String destination;
private int flighTime; // minutes past Midnight
private int flightDuration; // in minutes

// for example use LinkedList ArrayList HashSet ....
public void addPasagerToFlight(Passenger pas) {
    this.passengers.add(pas);
}
```

}